# How to modify "source" shell builtin?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, built-in

I'd like to modify the "source" shell builtin so that every time source is called the command "echo ${file I am sourcing}" is called.

I'd like to do this so that I can always tell which files have been sourced when I open a new bash instance.

Comment: You'll need to compile your own version of bash, then. It'll be easier if you just make an alias, or perhaps a local shell script in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new function:

```
mysource() { echo "sourcing file: $1" && source "$@"; }
```

But, if you really must call it `source`:

```
source() { echo "sourcing file: $1" && builtin source "$@"; }
```

Note that I am using `"$@"` so that any arguments after the filename are passed to the builtin `source` command too.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function in your shell:

```
source() { echo "$1"; . "$1"; }
```

This will only be valid for the shell in which the function is defined.  Put it in the appropriate startup file if you want it to be defined in all new shells.  (eg ~/.bashrc)